# Scaling MySQL Server for Handling High Volume Requests in a Multitenant Application

Tags: mysql, multi-tenant

I am currently working on developing a multi-tenant application where I have implemented a backend that identifies the tenant from the header and connects to the appropriate database.

However, I encountered an issue when attempting to create multiple databases and sending requests to the MySQL server. I consistently received an error indicating "too many connections."

I am seeking guidance on how to configure my MySQL server to handle a large number of requests, as my backend receives a significant influx of requests simultaneously. The high volume of database creation and simultaneous requests ultimately leads to a crash of my SQL server.

Comment: mysql should not just crash; investigate why it is crashing and address that as a separate question.  allowing more connections is just a configuration issue; aiui it isn't set very high by default because there's a non-zero memory cost, so calculate how many you need, add some to that just to be safe, and set max_connections in the config file.

Comment: Find your connection leak, use a connection pool.